# running eclipse from terminal in mac os x

Tags: eclipse, terminal

I've been trying to run eclipse from my mac os x terminal and I'm getting the error that no such eclipse command is found. I added the directory to my PATH variable and I'm able to run this just fine on linux, just not on mac osx.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Is there actually an executable file named "eclipse" there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eclipse is a Mac Application (like Mail.app) rather than a simple executable so you open it from Terminal using the `open` command:

```
open /Applications/eclipse.app
```

This is assuming you are using Eclipse Mars or later, earlier versions of Eclipse have a different path.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bin folder at my user root folder. This folder is added to my PATH env variable in my .bash_profile

Then I have an  ~/bin/eclipse file. this file is executable (chmod +x ~/bin/eclipse)

it contains 
open /Path/To/Eclipse.app

Hope this help